# To remove all comments in a JavaScript file, do we need just a scanner or also a parser?

Tags: parsers, lexical-analysis

I was asked how to remove comments in a JavaScript program, but once I gave the regular expression solution, I was asked what if there are comments like text inside of a string:

```
let hi = " // here ";
let foo = "   use this: /*   ";
let foo2 = "   \" and that */   ";
```

it also can get complicated with the cases with string being able to be quoted by `'` and the backtick `` ` ``:

```
let hi2 = 'here //';
let i = 123;
let hi3 = `here //  ${i  /* don't use j */}`;
let hi4 = `here //  ${i  // don't use j 
                         // because j is not good
                     }`;
let hi5 = ` and use there ' " \' \" \`  /*  */`;
let hi6 = ` this is really closing, not quoted backtick \\`;
let hi7 = `here //  ${i  /* don't use j in `` */}`;
```

So I mentioned a scanner (lexical analyzer) and a parser (like yacc or bison) can be used. So we can build a tree of node representing the program, and then wherever it is a comment type of node, we can remove it. (comment nodes have no children, I think? If they do, then can just change the comment to nothing, the empty string).

But is it true that all we need is a scanner?  We can tokenize all the text, and then we get each element which is a string, an operator, the left and right operands, and also the comment elements.

And then we can just remove all the comment elements and then reconstruct the program using all the tokens.

So probably we don't even need the program code to be represented as a tree, but just as a series of tokens.  So if we already have a scanner and parser, all we need is a scanner, and when we supply it with the proper grammar rules, we can remove all the comments?

(is the following considered grammar or just finite state automata and do we just use it to form the tokens?)

[image]

Comment: *when we supply [a scanner] with the proper grammar rules*—sorry, what? A scanner is little more than a finite automaton that emits tokens. It at best has regex capabilities (and not the uber-powerful perl kind, either). You need a parser to handle grammar rules.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble added a diagram to the end

Comment: Your last little diagram at the end can be handled by a finite state machine returning a single string literal token. But doesn't have to be, you can break your tokens up smaller and use a parser too. But FSM is minimum requirement for that one.

Comment: An example where you can not simply use a FSM is an expression with nested brackets. Because the recursive part of the production rule for the brackets will have a middle recursion that can not be rewritten into a left or right recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner (tokenizer) will be enough. Most programming languages do not allow comment nesting, so there is no need to use recursive parsers to strip all comments.

Comment: can your claim be substantiated a little bit more?

Comment: Are you assuming the input is valid? Bad idea.

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble - invalid input may lead to invalid result but also to correct result. But when input is invalid can you tell for sure what parts of input are comments? I don't think so.

Comment: @nopole - you have to write simple scanner. Write 4 simple regular expressions which will recognize (at begining of character stream) "string literals", 'string literals', /* comments */,  //comments. Then process input characters in loop: when current character is not in [",',/] put this character into output. In other case if character is in [",'] use regex to parse whole string literal and output it. If character is / then check with regex if this is comment -  if it is comment skip it, if not put / character / into output. That's all.

Comment: @ufok is it true it is more complicated because of the interpolation ``here //  ${i  /* don't use j */}`;` ? but I guess we can ignore interpolation for the moment to make it a simpler case

Comment: @nopole: Yes, if you have to deal with modern javascript's template literals, then a tokenizer is not sufficient. (Even string literals inside a template literal could cause problems.) However, the example of comments inside pre-template string literals is a red herring. The string literal will be tokenised as a unit, and so the characters inside it won't start a token. What you cannot do is just scan the input text with a regular expression which matches comments. That's not the same as tokenising.

Comment: I've thrown in a regex solution at the bottom of my answer. A for loop with a regex handling all four cases does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve it with a finite state machine, hand rolled lexer or even a regular expression (rather long regular expression). But I will throw in a quick and easy overkill solution. There is a project called "jison" which is like Bison, but for JavaScript (https://github.com/zaach/jison). It is a parser generator.

Here is a grammar you can use to strip comments everywhere except in strings:

```
/* description: Scripts comments from JavaScript code. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\/\*                  return 'BLOCK_COMMENT_START'
\*\/                  return 'BLOCK_COMMENT_END'
\/\/                  return 'LINE_COMMENT_START'
\"                    return 'DOUBLE_QUOTE'
'                     return 'SINGLE_QUOTE'
\\"                   return 'ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE'
\\'                   return 'ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE'
\\\\                  return 'ESCAPED_BACKSLASH'
\n                    return 'NEW_LINE'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'OTHER'

/lex

%start code

%% /* language grammar */

code
    : c EOF
        { typeof console !== 'undefined' ? console.log($1) : print($1);
        return $1; }
    | c LINE_COMMENT_START c3 EOF
        { typeof console !== 'undefined' ? console.log($1) : print($1);
        return $1; }
    ;


c
    : c OTHER {$$ = $1 + $2}
    | c BLOCK_COMMENT_START c2 BLOCK_COMMENT_END
    | c LINE_COMMENT_START c3 NEW_LINE
    | c DOUBLE_QUOTE c4 DOUBLE_QUOTE { $$ = $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 }
    | c SINGLE_QUOTE c5 SINGLE_QUOTE { $$ = $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 }
    | {$$ = ""}
    ;

c2
    : c2 any_except_block_comment_end
    | 
    ;

c3
    : c3 any_except_new_line
    | 
    ;

c4
    : c4 any_except_double_quote { $$ = $1 + $2 }
    | 
    ;

c5
    : c5 any_except_single_quote { $$ = $1 + $2 }
    |
    ;

any_except_block_comment_end
    : BLOCK_COMMENT_START
    | LINE_COMMENT_START
    | DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | SINGLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_BACKSLASH
    | NEW_LINE
    | EOF
    | OTHER
    ;

any_except_new_line
    : BLOCK_COMMENT_START
    | BLOCK_COMMENT_END
    | LINE_COMMENT_START
    | DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | SINGLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_BACKSLASH
    | EOF
    | OTHER
    ;

any_except_double_quote
    : BLOCK_COMMENT_START
    | BLOCK_COMMENT_END
    | LINE_COMMENT_START
    | SINGLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_BACKSLASH
    | NEW_LINE
    | EOF
    | OTHER
    ;

any_except_single_quote
    : BLOCK_COMMENT_START
    | BLOCK_COMMENT_END
    | LINE_COMMENT_START
    | DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE
    | ESCAPED_BACKSLASH
    | NEW_LINE
    | EOF
    | OTHER
    ;
```

Once again. Super overkill, but does the job. It generates an LR parser and since all recursions can be left-recursive, it will use constant stack space. And it will also run in linear time with regards to length of input.

The reason it should be achievable with just a finite state machine or regexp is that all the grammar can be rewritten to be using either just all left or just all right recursion. I do not have the regexp solution yet though.

I'll have a go at translating that LR grammar into a regular expression. But it will take a while.

Here is another solution too.
Just to prove it can be done via a finite state machine. Here is a finite state machine implemented in JavaScript for stripping out comments except for inside single quote and double quote strings:

```
var StripperState = {
    OUTSIDE: 0,
    ENTERING_BLOCK_COMMENT: 1,
    INSIDE_BLOCK_COMMENT: 2,
    LEAVING_BLOCK_COMMENT: 3,
    ENTERING_LINE_COMMENT: 4,
    INSIDE_LINE_COMMENT: 5,
    LEAVING_LINE_COMMENT: 6,
    INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING: 7,
    INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING: 8,
    ESCAPED_BACKSLASH_INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING: 9,
    ESCAPED_BACKSLASH_INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING: 10,
    ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE_INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING: 11,
    ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE_INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING: 12,
};

function make_stripper(ahead) {
    return {
        char: undefined,
        ahead: ahead,
        state: StripperState.OUTSIDE,
    };
}

function feed_stripper(stripper, char, consumer) {
    stripper.char = stripper.ahead;
    stripper.ahead = char;
    process(stripper, consumer);
}

function process(stripper, consumer) {
    switch (stripper.state) {
        case StripperState.OUTSIDE: {
            if (stripper.char == '/' && stripper.ahead == '*') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.ENTERING_BLOCK_COMMENT;
            } else if (stripper.char == '/' && stripper.ahead == '/') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.ENTERING_LINE_COMMENT;
            } else {
                if (stripper.char == '"') {
                    stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING;
                } else if (stripper.char == '\'') {
                    stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING;
                }
                consumer(stripper.char);
            }
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.ENTERING_BLOCK_COMMENT: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '*');
            stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_BLOCK_COMMENT;
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.INSIDE_BLOCK_COMMENT: {
            if (stripper.char == '*' && stripper.ahead == '/') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.LEAVING_BLOCK_COMMENT;
            }
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.LEAVING_BLOCK_COMMENT: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '/');
            stripper.state = StripperState.OUTSIDE;
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.ENTERING_LINE_COMMENT: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '/');
            stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_LINE_COMMENT;
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.INSIDE_LINE_COMMENT: {
            if (stripper.char == '\r' && stripper.ahead == '\n') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.LEAVING_LINE_COMMENT;
            } else if (stripper.char == '\n') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.OUTSIDE;
            } else if (stripper.char == '\r') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.OUTSIDE;
            }
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.LEAVING_LINE_COMMENT: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '\n');
            stripper.state = StripperState.OUTSIDE;
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING: {
            if (stripper.char == '"') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.OUTSIDE;
            } else if (stripper.char == '\\' && stripper.ahead == '\\') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.ESCAPED_BACKSLASH_INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            } else if (stripper.char == '\\' && stripper.ahead == '"') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE_INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            }
            consumer(stripper.char);
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING: {
            if (stripper.char == '\'') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.OUTSIDE;
            } else if (stripper.char == '\\' && stripper.ahead == '\\') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.ESCAPED_BACKSLASH_INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            } else if (stripper.char == '\\' && stripper.ahead == '\'') {
                stripper.state = StripperState.ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE_INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            }
            consumer(stripper.char);
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.ESCAPED_BACKSLASH_INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '\\');
            stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            consumer(stripper.char);
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.ESCAPED_BACKSLASH_INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '\\');
            stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            consumer(stripper.char);
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.ESCAPED_DOUBLE_QUOTE_INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '"');
            stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            consumer(stripper.char);
            break;
        }
        case StripperState.ESCAPED_SINGLE_QUOTE_INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING: {
            console.assert(stripper.char == '\'');
            stripper.state = StripperState.INSIDE_SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING;
            consumer(stripper.char);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function strip_comments_from_code(code) {
    if (code.length == 0) {
        return code;
    }
    var stripper = make_stripper(code[0]);
    var result = '';
    var consumer = function(char) {
        result += char;
    };
    for (var i = 1; i < code.length; ++i) {
        feed_stripper(stripper, code[i], consumer);
    }
    feed_stripper(stripper, undefined, consumer);
    return result;
}

var code = "te/*st*/ // /* aaa vvv */\ncd. ' /* er */ '";
console.log(strip_comments_from_code(code));
```

The code doesn't know about backtick strings, but that can be an exercise for the reader. Also if you throw in a counter in the stripper state you can handle nested comments, but then it is no longer a finite state machine anymore.

Here is the regular expression:
`/^(\/\*((?!\*)(.|\n|\r)|\*(?!\/)(.|\n|\r))*\*\/|"((?!("|\\))(.|\n|\r)|\\(.|\n|\r))*"|'((?!('|\\))(.|\n|\r)|\\(.|\n|\r))*'|\/\/.*(\r\n?|\n|$)|((?!(\/|"|'))(.|\n|\r)))*/g`

There is a couple of groups in that regular expression that will match comments outside strings. Now we just need a way to substitute only certain groups in the regex to a empty string.

Finally a regex solution:

```
var regex = /^(("((?!("|\\))(.|\n|\r)|\\(.|\n|\r))*"|'((?!('|\\))(.|\n|\r)|\\(.|\n|\r))*'|((?!(\/|"|'))(.|\n|\r)))*)(\/\*((?!\*)(.|\n|\r)|\*(?!\/)(.|\n|\r))*\*\/|\/\/.*(\r\n?|\n|$))/g;
var code = "te/*st*/ aaa // bbb \n ' /* ccc */' ";
var l = code.length;
while (true) {
    code = code.replace(regex, "$1");
    if (code.length == l) {
        break;
    }
    l = code.length;
}
console.log(code);
```